# \edef, \xdef and \ifmmode

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, expansion

I don't understand the difference between `\edef` and `\xdef` in the following code. Clearly, the `\xdef` does what I'm expecting but why? AFAIK, `$` does not start a group.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

$\edef\bar{\ifmmode\noexpand\true\else\noexpand\false\fi}$ 
\meaning\bar

$\xdef\bar{\ifmmode\noexpand\true\else\noexpand\false\fi}$
\meaning\bar

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `$` does start a group

Comment: Try `a $\mathsurround=10pt b$ a $b$ a` and you'll see that the setting of `\mathsurround` does not extend to the second formula. This is because `$` starts a group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a math list forms a group so the first `\edef` definition is discarded and `\meaning` shows the original definition.

The definition with `\xdef` is the same, but is visible outside the group closed by the trailing `$`.