# \write and \ifmmode

Tags: math-mode, tex-core, write

This is related to a [previous question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267153/8425) (if I understand correctly, `\write` works a bit like `\edef`).

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert={size=640}]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\newwrite\foo
\immediate\openout\foo=foo.txt
$\immediate\write\foo{\ifmmode\noexpand\true\else\noexpand\false\fi}$ 
\immediate\closeout\foo

\VerbatimInput{foo.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to write `\true` to the file. How can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some variations.

### The fun of `\expandafter`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert={size=640}]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\newwrite\foo
\immediate\openout\foo=foo.txt
$\immediate\expandafter\write\expandafter\foo\expandafter{%
  \ifmmode\noexpand\true\else\noexpand\false\fi}$ 
\immediate\closeout\foo

\VerbatimInput{foo.txt}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The `\expandafter` expands `\ifmmode` while in math mode, before `\write` is executed.

### Expanded macro definitions:

```
$\edef\result{\ifmmode\string\true\else\string\false\fi}
  \immediate\write\foo{\result}$
```

Or the whole expression can be put in an `\edef`:

```
$\edef\next{%
  \immediate\write\foo{\ifmmode\string\true\else\string\false\fi}%
}\next$
```

Answer (score 9):

Inside a `\write`, TeX is in 'no mode', not in hmode,  math mode, *etc.* Thus you have to move the test outside of the `\write`

```
$
  \ifmmode
     \immediate\write\foo{\string\true}%
  \else
    \immediate\write\foo{\string\false}%
  \fi}
$
```

Comment: @cjorssen what do you mean?

Comment: No hope to keep the test inside `\write`?

Comment: @cjorssen No: you can't set the mode yourself other than locally redefining the meaning of `\ifmmode`, `\ifhmode` and `\ifvmode`, which of course will have unwanted consequences: if you set `\ifmmode` to `\iftrue` and you have in the argument to `\write` something like `\hbox{\foo}`, where `\foo` expands to `\ifmmode a\else b\fi`, the result will be wrong.